# Trying to map from one domain class to view model class skips properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, entity-framework-core

I am having a very weird issue. I am creating an ASP.Net Core front end website and an ASP.Net Core back end API. The back end API uses Entity Framework Core for persistence.

I use a view model class to post the data from the website to the API, then I use AutoMapper to map from the view model class to the entity class to pass it to the EF based repository. This has worked for two other view model / entity class relationships in this project related to other database tables.

However, I am adding a new database table and related view model / entity class set that is giving me this weird problem.

With this particular entity / view model relationship, Automapper fails with no error. It just skips over any property that isn't defined in the entity class with a question mark after the data type (making the property nullable).

I created a method to manually map the properties, one by one, from the view model class to the entity class and I am seeing the same issue, so I believe it is not specifically an AutoMapper issue.

Here is my  entity class;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace API.Models
{
    public partial class UserFeaturesEvs
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public string LoginNickname { get; set; }
        public string CarrierLoginName { get; set; }
        public string CarrierLoginPassword { get; set; }
        public int CarrierId { get; set; }
        public int? CarrierLoginId { get; set; }
        public string PermitNumber { get; set; }
        public string PermitType { get; set; }
        public string PermitName { get; set; }
        public int? McdPrimaryId { get; set; }
        public string Crid { get; set; }
        public string CapsId { get; set; }
        public bool? IsGovernment { get; set; }
        public string CityStateOfPo { get; set; }
        public string PoOfAccountZip { get; set; }
        public string MasterMid { get; set; }
        public string ChildMid { get; set; }
        public string IndiciaText { get; set; }
        public string LoginId { get; set; }
        public string PostageType { get; set; }
        public int? SiteId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is my view model class;

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace API.ViewModels.EVS
{
    public class UserFeaturesEvsViewModel
    {
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "User ID")] 
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Carrier ID")]
        [Required]
        public int CarrierId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Site ID")]
        public int SiteId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nick Name")]
        public string LoginNickname { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Login Name")]
        [Required]
        public string CarrierLoginName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Required]
        public string CarrierLoginPassword { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Carrier Login ID")]
        public int CarrierLoginId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "MCD Primary ID")] 
        public int McdPrimaryId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Permit Number")]
        public string PermitNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Permit Type")]
        public string PermitType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Permit Name")]
        public string PermitName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "CRID")]
        public string Crid { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "CAPS ID")]
        public string EvsCapsId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Government Permit")]
        public bool EvsGovernmentPermit { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "PO of Account - City/State")]
        public string EvsCityStateOfPo { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "PO of Account - Zipcode")]
        public string EvsPoOfAccountZip { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Master MID")
        public string EvsMasterMid { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Child ID")]
        public string EvsChildMid { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Indicia Text")]
        public string EvsIndiciaText { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Login ID")]
        public string EvsLoginId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Postage Type")]
        public string PostageType { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is the test method I created in the API controller class to manually map from the view model class to the entity class

```
    private UserFeaturesEvs MapUserFeaturesEvsViewModelToUserFeaturesEvs(UserFeaturesEvsViewModel a_model)
    {
        try
        {
            UserFeaturesEvs model = new UserFeaturesEvs();
            if (a_model != null)
            {
                model.SiteId = a_model.SiteId;
                model.Active = a_model.Active;
                model.UserId = a_model.UserId;
                model.CarrierId = a_model.CarrierId;
                model.LoginNickname = a_model.LoginNickname;
                model.CarrierLoginName = a_model.CarrierLoginName;
                model.CarrierLoginPassword = a_model.CarrierLoginPassword;
                model.CarrierLoginId = a_model.CarrierLoginId;
                model.McdPrimaryId = a_model.McdPrimaryId;
                model.PermitNumber = a_model.PermitNumber;
                model.PermitType = a_model.PermitType;
                model.PermitName = a_model.PermitName;
                model.Crid = a_model.Crid;
                model.CapsId = a_model.EvsCapsId;
                model.IsGovernment = a_model.EvsGovernmentPermit;
                model.CityStateOfPo = a_model.EvsCityStateOfPo;
                model.PoOfAccountZip = a_model.EvsPoOfAccountZip;
                model.MasterMid = a_model.EvsMasterMid;
                model.ChildMid = a_model.EvsChildMid;
                model.IndiciaText = a_model.EvsIndiciaText;
                model.LoginId = a_model.EvsLoginId;
                model.PostageType = a_model.PostageType;
            }
            return model;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            m_logger.LogError(1, ex, "An exception occurred in the MapUserFeaturesEvsViewModelToUserFeaturesEvs method while trying to map the UserFeaturesEvsViewModel [{VM}] to the UserFeaturesEvs Model.", a_model);
            return null;
        }
```

Now, I can see the problem occurring as I single step in Visual Studio 2015, through the MapUserFeaturesEvsViewModelToUserFeaturesEvs method using F11. Once I step past the if (a_model != null) line, the debug only stops on the lines for the SiteId, CarrierLoginId, McdPrimaryId and EvsGovernmentPermit, skipping all of the others. And the returned UserFeaturesEvs object only has data in those 4 fields. I confirmed that the UserFeaturesEvsViewModel object passed into the method has data in all of the properties.

The UserFeatruesEvs class properties that are being successfully assigned data are just the ones that have nullable data types signified by the ? after the data type, as shown in the property excerpts from the UserFeaturesEvs class, below;

```
        public int? CarrierLoginId { get; set; }
        public int? McdPrimaryId { get; set; }
        public bool? IsGovernment { get; set; }
        public int? SiteId { get; set; }
```

The entity class, UserFeaturesEvs was generated from an existing database table using the..

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold ...
```

...command.

The above command line command also adds the code below to the DBContext class...

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserFeaturesEvs>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.UserId)
                .HasName("PK_UserFeatures_EVS");

            entity.ToTable("UserFeatures_EVS");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .HasColumnName("UserID")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.CapsId)
                .HasColumnName("CapsID")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.CarrierId).HasColumnName("CarrierID");

            entity.Property(e => e.CarrierLoginId).HasColumnName("CarrierLoginID");

            entity.Property(e => e.CarrierLoginName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.CarrierLoginPassword)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.ChildMid)
                .HasColumnName("ChildMID")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.CityStateOfPo)
                .HasColumnName("CityStateOfPO")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.Crid)
                .HasColumnName("CRID")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.IndiciaText).HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.LoginId).HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.LoginNickname).HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.MasterMid)
                .HasColumnName("MasterMID")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.McdPrimaryId).HasColumnName("MCDPrimaryID");

            entity.Property(e => e.PermitName).HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.PermitNumber).HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.PermitType).HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.PoOfAccountZip)
                .HasColumnName("PoOfAccountZip")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.PostageType).HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

            entity.Property(e => e.SiteId).HasColumnName("SiteID");
        });

    }

    public virtual DbSet<UserFeaturesEvs> UserFeaturesEvs { get; set; }

.
.
.
```

I can't see anything that is causing this issue and , like I said earlier, I have used this same entity class / view model class technique with two other database tables with no problem.

All of the code I am talking about above is in the ASP.Net Core API project.

I tried removing the ? from the data type declarations in the UserFeaturesEvs class properties and when I did that, the debugger just skipped over all of the property assignments and returned all null data from the mapping method.

**EDIT:** Further analysis shows that the issue is with the UserFeaturesEvsViewModel. I can statically assign values to the UserFeaturesEvs object instance in the MapUserFeaturesEvsViewModelToUserFeaturesEvs method and it does not skip over the property assignments that do not have ? after their datatype declaration. As this is an API, the UserFeatruesEvsViewModel is coming from a Create method in the API controller.

```
    [HttpPost("")]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody]UserFeaturesEvsViewModel a_vm)
    {
        try
        {
            //Test assignment of vm to local variables
            int SiteId = a_vm.SiteId;   // This gets skipped
            bool Active = a_vm.Active;  // This gets skipped
            int UserId = a_vm.UserId;   // This gets skipped
            int CarrierId = a_vm.CarrierId; // This gets skipped
            string LoginNickname = a_vm.LoginNickname; // This gets skipped

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UserFeaturesEvs model = MapUserFeaturesEvsViewModelToUserFeaturesEvs(a_vm);

                //UserFeaturesEvs model = Mapper.Map<UserFeaturesEvs>(a_vm);
                .
                .
                .
```

This is a sample of the JSON I am posting as application/json to the API controller from the Google Chrome Postman app

```
{
  "active": true,
  "userId": 1,
  "carrierId": 1,
  "siteId": 1,
  "loginNickname": "testNickname",
  "carrierLoginName": "testLoginName",
  "carrierLoginPassword": "testLoginPassword",
  "carrierLoginId": 0,
  "mcdPrimaryId": 0,
  "permitNumber": "123456",
  "permitType": "",
  "permitName": "UserID1-123456",
  "crid": "11",
  "evsCapsId": "112233",
  "evsGovernmentPermit": false,
  "evsCityStateOfPo": "Somewhere, NY",
  "evsPoOfAccountZip": "90210",
  "evsMasterMid": "654321",
  "evsChildMid": "654322",
  "evsIndiciaText": "Test",
  "evsLoginId": "",
  "postageType": "P"
}
```

When I view the a_vm in the debugger, I see the data I am posting and it appears to be in the structure of the UserVeaturesEvsViewModel class. However, when I try to simply assign properties of the a_vm variable to local variables at the start of the Create method, as shown above, those assignments are also just skipped over by the debugger (even if I put a breakpoint on the assignments), just like what is happening in the MapUserFeaturesEvsViewModelToUserFeaturesEvs method.

In the other API controllers where I am not having this issue, I am passing the a_vm object into my Entity Framework repository. For example, the code below in another controller of this same API works just fine.

```
    [HttpPost("")]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody]MerSettingsViewModel a_vm)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                MailEventsRetrieverSettings settings = Mapper.Map<MailEventsRetrieverSettings>(a_vm);
                Task<MailEventsRetrieverSettings> task = m_cdiMppsRepository.AddMailEventsRetrieverSettingsAsync(settings);
                MailEventsRetrieverSettings response = task.Result;
                if (response != null)
                {
                    return Ok(response);
                }
            }
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            m_logger.LogError(1, ex, "Could not create new MailEventsRetrieverSettings record for the following object [{@VM}] to the database", a_vm);
            return Json(new { Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

So, the problem seems to be coming from the way the object is automatically deserialized from the body of the HttpPost in the Create method. Even though, in the debugger, I see the values in a_vm and it appears to be structured correctly, I can't directly assign the values of those properties to another class property or local variable if the class property or local variable is not defined as nullable.

Any ideas?

Comment: So it only works for nullable properties?

Comment: They to Delete your entire bin folder and do a rebuild and retry.

Comment: Why is your model class partial? Could you show the other parts of this class?

Comment: @Coding Yoshi - Yes, it only works for nullable properties

Comment: @Pawel Manga - The UserFeaturesEva class gets defined as a partial class when it is created by Entity Framework Core when I used the "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold ..." command line command. That command generates the UserFeaturesEvs class as well as the code for the dbcontext's OnModelCreating method for odelBuilder.Entity<UserFeaturesEvs>(entity =>
            { ...});  and the public virtual DBset<UserFeaturesEvs> UserfeaturesEvs { get; set;} declaration.

Comment: @Pawel Manga - I added the code that the "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold..." cenerated in my DBContext class to my post above for your review.

Comment: @Coding Yoshi - I deleted the contents of my solution's bin folder and then rebuilt the solution. I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: @Pawel Manga - I removed the word "partial" from my class and I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: @EiEiGuy when you are setting the properties of `model` try setting them with hard coded values and see what happens. If that works then we have narrowed down the issue.

Comment: @CodingYoshi - See my edit in my original post. It appears that the issue is in the view model object

Comment: @EiEiGuy in your create method, try creating a local variable like this `var vm = a_vm;` and then use `vm` instead. See if that makes a difference. I am out of ideas as the issue is really weird.

Comment: @CodingYoshi - I did the `var vm = a_vm;` as you suggested and then tried assigning values .. `int SiteId = vm.SiteId;` but the debugger still just skips over it. This seems like it has to be something in the way `[FromBody]` is deserializing the JSON

Comment: @Coding Yoshi  - Here is the newest update on the issue. It seems that this issue only shows up if I have the project in release mode. If I leave it in debug, I seem to map OK. But if I put it into release mode and deploy to staging, it fails at the point where it is trying to map between the two classes. If I deploy to staging while leaving the project in debug mode, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Automapper, but reading over their wiki it is stated:

> AutoMapper will ignore null reference exceptions when mapping your source to your target. This is by design.

You are validating the object already- try seeing if the values you are passing are coming up null.

Comment: I did verify that all of the properties of the UserFeaturesEvsViewModel object instance I am passing in to the method has values, as stated in my original post. They are just not getting assigned to the properties of the UserFeaturesEvs object instance unless that property in the UserFeatruesEvs has a question mark after its data type declaration in the object's class.

Comment: Regarding Automapper, it may ignore null reference exceptions but in the example I show in my post, I am not using Automapper. I am manually mapping the properties between the two class objects to try to identify why Automapper was failing and I am getting the same behavior without Automapper.

Comment: @joseph the code in question is not using automapper and even if he was the properties which are failing are not reference types.